# Have I created my DMZ in OpenWRT correctly? Is there anything further I need to do?

Tags: networking, router, routing, firewall, openwrt

I'm doing this all in Luci. [Here is my /etc/config/network](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/i3xF2KKokPLeBPZZCaqZtA) and [my /etc/config/firewall is here](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/nOdMdr2s1Df5RAAtfTe8mg), but these are just what are created by the Luci interface. I'm not sure if there are any other relevant files I should include.

So my goal is to create a DMZ for my home server (currently situated at 192.168.96.123 which I believe to be correctly on my DMZ) which has a few internet-facing ports.

First, I created a vlan for my router's lan port 1 (which holds my server):
[image: switch interface]

VLAN 3 is the DMZ vlan, and 1 and 2 are as they came out of the box (aside from me switching the lan ports from "untagged" to "off" on VLAN 1)

Next, I created the interface. It uses an IP in 192.168.96.0/24 (while the rest of my network uses 192.168.86.0/24), is not set to bridge anything right now because it's just a single port.

[image: interface]
and
[image: interface]
and
[image: interface]

And finally, my firewall settings. I've added no custom routing yet because it doesn't seem to be needed.

[image: firewall]

So, with everything in these screenshots, I've tested things out and they *seem* to be in order. I can ssh to the server just fine, but I can't so much as ping the gateway from the server, and traffic seems to pass normally with the internet. So I believe it's working correctly now, but I've never done this before so I wanted to see if anyone sees anything wrong with what's been done here.